# Is it possible to display the contents of [object FileList] in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, filelist

```
if(this.all.length > 0){
    for(var k=0; k<this.all.length; k++){               
        alert(this.all[k]);  // it alerts [object FileList] 
        var file = this.all[k];
        this._uploader(file,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "alter"? Change? Or did you actually mean "iterate"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(this.all.length > 0){
    for(var k=0, len = this.all.length; k < len; k++){               
        console.dir(this.all[k]);  // will iterate over the properties of each  [object FileList] in the console
        var file = this.all[k];
        this._uploader(file,0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this for debugging purposes, I suggest you to use console.log:

```
console.log(this.all[k])
```

If you insist on alerting the thing for whatever reason, you can serialize it with JSON.stringify:

```
JSON.stringify(this.all[k])
```

However, console.log is really much nicer: less annoying, and you can inspect the objects easily.